# How can I set a javascript variable to "" if it is undefined?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
var viewID = $(link).data('dialog-id')
```

This works when there is a dialog-id value. But when there is no value then viewID gets the value of "undefined".

Is there a way that I can make the value of viewID be equal to an empty string if dialog-id is not available or be equal to dialog-id if it is available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
var viewID = $(link).data('dialog-id') || '';
```

Which works thanks to the way Javascript handles [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 3):

```
var viewID = $(link).data('dialog-id') == undefined ? "" : $(link).data('dialog-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately:

```
var viewID = $(link).data('dialog-id')
if (viewID == null) {
    viewID = '';
}
```

This also works, since `undefined` and `null` are considered equal.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `||` operator

```
var viewID = $(link).data('dialog-id') || '';
```

The '||' operator takes a value on the left and right.  If the value on the left is truthy then it will be returned else the right value will be.  The value `undefined` is falsy hence if it's returned from the `data('dialog-id')` call then it will pick `''` instead